# Frechet Differentiability of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, frechet-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and define the functional $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\,ds$.

Now define the functional $G:W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $G(u)=\int_{\Omega}F(u)\,dx.$

Then $G$ is Frechet differentiable and $<G'(u),\phi>=\int_{\Omega}f(u)\phi\,dx$ for all $\phi\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

I have checked that $G$ is Gateaux differentiable in the sense that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{G(u+t\phi)-G(u)}{t}=\int_{\Omega}f(u)\phi\,dx=<G'(u),\phi>.$$

Now to prove $G$ is Frechet differentiable which is generally referred as $C^1$, we need to prove that $G'$ is continuous, that is for every $u_n\to u$, one has $G'(u_n)\to G'(u)$.

First of all it is not clear to me, whether for such continuous $f$, $G'$ is always continuous.

If somebody kindly clarify the same, it would help me a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify, how do you get the Gateaux derivative? I get $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{G(u+t \psi)- G(u)}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_\Omega (\int_0^{(u(x)+t \psi(x)} f(s)ds - \int_0^{u(x)} f(s) dx) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_\Omega \int_{u(x)}^{(u(x)+t \psi(x)} f(s)ds dx.$$

Comment: Or should $F(u)(x)$ actually be $\int_0^x u(t) dt$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven It's fine, take the limit in t inside the interval and you get the Gateaux derivative $\int_\Omega f(u)\psi\, dx$.

Comment: To prove Frechet differentiability, you need to examine the linearization error $\|G(u+v)-G(u) - G'(u)v\|/\|v\|$ and show this tends to zero as $\|v\|\to 0$, where $\|\cdot \|$ is the norm on your domain space ($W^{1,p}$). Have you tried this? Where do you get stuck? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, was confusing variables :)